# Embed a win32 dll in .net Project

Tags: .net, dll, fortran, embed, .net-assembly

Is it possible to embed a win32 .dll into a .net project? Ideally I don't want to distribute a .dll along with a .exe. I've read about using AssemblyReslove for .net dll's ([here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx)) but it doesn't seem to be working for my .dll's (created with the Intel Fortran compiler). Firstly the event "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve" never gets called. However even if I force an assembly load before using the .dll I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.
>   Additional information: Could not load file or assembly '16896 bytes loaded from DLLtest2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong - or another approach I could try?

Code used for Assembly Load:

```
using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("DLLtest2.Dll1.dll"))
{
   byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
   stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
   Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Assembly.Load` loads .Net assembly only. If it's not a .Net assembly, then it won't load it

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I feared that may be the case! Any idea how/if it's possible to load non-.net assemblies using a different technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assembly.Load is for .NET (managed) assemblies only. For native DLLs you need to use PInvoke.

- http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/C%23+Interoperability
- http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/calling-fortran-function-or-subroutine-in-dll-from-c-code/

Given the following (Intel) Fortran subroutine:

```
subroutine DoWork(n, A)
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: DoWork
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS: 'DoWork' :: DoWork
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: n, A
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    real(8), dimension(n, n), intent(inout) :: A
end subroutine
```

Use the following method signature in the C# code.

```
[DllImport("FortranStuff.dll", EntryPoint = "DoWork", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void DoWork(ref int n, [In, Out] double[,] A);
```

In this example, FortranStuff.dll needs to be in the same directory as the calling assembly. You could modify the attribute to use a relative or absolute file path ("..\bin\FortranStuff.dll"), but I would recommend just placing it side by side to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so! they must be linked in compiling time! and if you embed in you program i think it can be simple to decompile it and save the dll